# how do I pass multiple parameters from jshelper to apex controller in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, parameters

I would like to pass two strings to my apex controller, but I keep getting an illegal argument error in my debugger.

jshelper-

```
    var toDate = cmp.get("v.toDate");
    var dateStr = toDate.toString();
    console.log('date string is', dateStr);
    var addTime = cmp.get("v.statNum");
    console.log('passing time = ', addTime);
    var action = cmp.get("c.getDate");
    action.setParams({"addDate" : dateStr, "addTime" : addTime});
```

apex controller-

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static Date getDate(string addDate, string addTime){
    system.debug(addTime);
    system.debug(addDate);
```

Comment: Can you add more code here .Like your component attribute declaration

Comment: @Mohith Shrivastava   `<aura:attribute name="toDate" type="Date" default=""/>`

`<aura:attribute name="statNum" type="String"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok so this is actually the correct way to pass two arguments from helper to apex. the issue was that I had to convert my addTime to a string (even though in my component it was of type String). working code below

js-

```
    var toDate = cmp.get("v.toDate");
    var dateStr = toDate.toString();
    var addTime = cmp.get("v.statNum");
    var addTimeStr = addTime.toString();
    var action = cmp.get("c.getDate");
    action.setParams({"addDate" : dateStr, "addTime" : addTimeStr});
```

apex

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Date getDate(string addDate, string addTime){
    system.debug(addTime);
    system.debug(addDate);
```

Comment: You know, you could have made addDate a date parameter.

Comment: @sfdcfox I tried to do that but it wouldn't pass the date from javascript to apex. it kept returning null.  any idea why?

Comment: Probably because you were using Date.toString(). If you'd left it as a Date, it should have come across okay.

Comment: @sfdcfox my Date.toString was a work around because it kept passing as null. I think maybe js typecasted the Date wrong or something? maybe I should have used let instead of var? or used .get() instead of creating a variable and then passing it.

Comment: I cannot send a date type. I sent a string and converted it in the apex class